# Curl minikube apiserver using client certs for authentication

Tags: curl, kubernetes, minikube, client-certificates

Basic question about authenticating to minikube api-server using curl with client cert and key.

When I curl `/ping` endpoint on api-server, I get back a 403 (expected, fails authentication)

`curl -k https://127.0.0.1:32776/ping`

```json
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get path \"/ping\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {

  },
  "code": 403
}
```

And to fix the same, I'm trying the below curl command I'm using

```sh
curl -v
--cert /Users/blah/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt \
--cacert /Users/blah/.minikube/ca.cert \
--key /Users/blah/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key \
https://127.0.0.1:32776/ping
```

and I get back

```sh
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:32776...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 32776 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* WARNING: SSL: CURLOPT_SSLKEY is ignored by Secure Transport. The private key must be in the Keychain.
* WARNING: SSL: Certificate type not set, assuming PKCS#12 format.
* SSL: Can't find the certificate "/Users/blah/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt" and its private key in the Keychain.
* Closing connection 0
curl: (58) SSL: Can't find the certificate "/Users/blah/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt" and its private key in the Keychain.
```

I'm using the above certs as described in
`kubectl config view`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /Users/blah/.minikube/ca.crt
    server: https://127.0.0.1:32776
  name: minikube
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: minikube
    user: minikube
  name: minikube
current-context: minikube
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: minikube
  user:
    client-certificate: /Users/blah/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.crt
    client-key: /Users/blah/.minikube/profiles/minikube/client.key
```

I think this is more of curl usage details that I'm missing, minikube seems to be fine.
Also, I'm curious how others authenticating curl requests to minikube?

Answer (score 0):

what curl version you use? and what OS? Isn't it [MacOSX](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/4801)?

Very similar issue [Error when trying to access API via curl](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/16107), where also valid present certificate hasnt seen. Resolution was to convert key to `pkcs12`.

RaeesBhatti in [How to access Kubernetes API using CURL](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/609) post also suggests

> I found out that I was using wrong certificates and the SSL: Can't
> load the certificate [] and its private key: OSStatus -25299 is a
> [problem specific to CURL in OS X Mavericks+](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2014-10/0053.html) where CURL accepts
> certificates of only P12 format. You have to use certificates in
> $HOME/.minikube/ directory instead $HOME/.minikube/certs. You also
> have to [convert the certificates into P12](https://coderwall.com/p/h3zzrw/using-client-ssl-certificates-for-php-curl-requests-on-osx) format and then use them.